# what is the replica for UDID or UUID in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

Problem is once I am generating `UUID` its working for me. But if me/user delete the application than `UUID` is not same like i have generated before. There is no uniqueness here if we are using uuid as identifier. Please help me to solve this issue.How can i get same uuid or any string if application reinstalled.
Thanks in advance..

I am using this approach:

```
NSString *udid;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
    udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
else
    udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Answer (score 2):

First, check this very informative post on NSHiplster http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/

This should be working for you:

```
NSString *UUIDString = nil;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 6.0) {
    UUIDString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
} else {
    CFUUIDRef UUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    UUIDString = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, UUID));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by using advertisingIdentifier. 
Link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#jumpTo_3

As I have seen there that advertisingIdentifier is

> "An alphanumeric string unique to each device, ..."

For that I have used it as the unique identifier (though it is used for the
serving advertisements).

My code is:

```
-(NSString*)UniqueAppId
{
    NSString *Appname = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:Appname account:@"manab"];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
    {
        strApplicationUUID  = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:Appname account:@"manab"];
    }
    return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

and just calling it when needed as

```
[self UniqueAppId];
```

Comment: Note in the link above `"This identifier may change—for example, if the user erases the device..."`