# How can I get unique number of device or iPad in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

As apple not supported to get the real UDID from iOS 7. I need any unique ID of the device that needs to be same every time of that particular iPad or device.

Is there any other way to get the unique number of that particular device and that should not be change any time. So we can use to identify the device in the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `identifierForVendor` property or the `advertisingIdentifier` property of the [ASIdentifierManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ASIdentifierManager) class instead. Or use the `UUID` method of the [NSUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUUID) class to create a `UUID` and write it to the user defaults database.

For example :https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676017/616094

Comment: thanks, is this same any time? even if I install and reinstall the apps and with different provisional profiles app?

Comment: No, it depends on vendor. If vendor changes value will be changed too. Search for MAC address may be it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Can't use MAC anymore, it returns the same value for all devices and is very much *not* unique on iOS 7+.

Comment: @Tim: Than `identifierForVendor` is better option.

Answer (score 0):

See [`-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor).

Comment: Tim, thanks, is this same any time? even if I install and reinstall the apps and with different provisional profiles app?

Comment: The Identifier For Vendor will not change as long as the user has any one of your applications on their device.  Once they delete all of your organization's applications from the device, it can change.  Does your application really require that the identifier not change even if they delete your app?  How many users actually delete your app and reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]
```

Its available 6.0 and above os version.